# Model structure for regression from images

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, deep-learning, neural-network

I'm trying to build a tensorflow model for analysing board games, so I started with a simpler 2D dataset. I generated 1000 images of black semicircles like these:

[image: input image 1] [image: input image 2]

I thought it would be a good exercise to try and recover the angle of the flat side. I labeled these two example images as 210.474° and 147.593°.

Unfortunately, the results I get are terrible. All the predictions on the test data are roughly 180°, presumably close to the mean value of the labels.

Can anyone give me advice on how to improve my model architecture or otherwise improve my results? If all of the input data is boolean pixels, do I need to normalize it?

I create the model like this:

```
def build_and_compile_model():
    num_channels = 200
    kernel_size = 3
    image_height = 64
    image_width = 64
    regularizer = regularizers.l2(0.0001)

    model = keras.Sequential(
        [layers.Conv2D(num_channels,
                       kernel_size,
                       padding='same',
                       activation='relu',
                       input_shape=(image_height, image_width, 1),
                       activity_regularizer=regularizer),
         layers.Dense(64, activation='relu'),
         layers.Dense(64, activation='relu'),
         layers.Dense(1)])

    model.compile(loss='mean_absolute_error',
                  optimizer=tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(0.001))
    return model
```

When I try to fit the model, it improves for a few epochs, then stabilizes at a high error.

[image: Plot of model training]

Here's the complete example:

```
import math
import shutil
import typing
from datetime import datetime
from pathlib import Path

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from PIL import Image, ImageDraw
import tensorflow as tf
from space_tracer import LivePillowImage
from tensorflow import keras
from tensorflow.python.keras import layers, regularizers


def build_and_compile_model():
    num_channels = 200
    kernel_size = 3
    image_height = 64
    image_width = 64
    regularizer = regularizers.l2(0.0001)

    model = keras.Sequential(
        [layers.Conv2D(num_channels,
                       kernel_size,
                       padding='same',
                       activation='relu',
                       input_shape=(image_height, image_width, 1),
                       activity_regularizer=regularizer),
         layers.Dense(64, activation='relu'),
         layers.Dense(64, activation='relu'),
         layers.Dense(1)])

    model.compile(loss='mean_absolute_error',
                  optimizer=tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(0.001))
    return model


def main():
    image_folder = Path(__file__).parent / 'circle_images'
    num_images = 1000
    image_data, label_data = read_input_data(num_images, image_folder)

    # Make NumPy printouts easier to read.
    np.set_printoptions(precision=3, suppress=True)

    image_count = image_data.shape[0]
    image_data = image_data.reshape(image_data.shape + (1, ))

    train_size = math.floor(image_count * 0.8)
    train_dataset = image_data[:train_size, :, :]
    test_dataset = image_data[train_size:, :, :]
    train_labels = label_data[:train_size]
    test_labels = label_data[train_size:]

    test_results = {}

    dnn_model = build_and_compile_model()

    print('training dataset:', train_dataset.shape)
    print('training labels:', train_labels.shape)

    start = datetime.now()
    history = dnn_model.fit(
        train_dataset,
        train_labels,
        validation_split=0.2,
        verbose=0, epochs=25)
    print('Trained for', datetime.now() - start)

    test_results['dnn_model'] = dnn_model.evaluate(test_dataset, test_labels, verbose=0)
    print(pd.DataFrame(test_results, index=['Mean absolute error [game value]']).T)

    test_predictions = dnn_model.predict(test_dataset).flatten()
    print(test_labels[:10])
    print(test_predictions[:10])

    plot_loss(history)


def create_images(num_images: int, image_folder: Path) -> None:
    print(f'Creating {num_images} images.')
    image_folder.mkdir()
    start_angles = np.random.random(num_images)
    start_angles *= 360
    rng = np.random.default_rng()
    rng.shuffle(start_angles)
    for i, start_angle in enumerate(start_angles):
        image_path = image_folder / f'image{i}.png'
        image = create_image(start_angle)
        image.save(image_path)
    label_text = '\n'.join(str(start_angle) for start_angle in start_angles)
    (image_folder / 'labels.csv').write_text(label_text)


def create_image(start_angle: float) -> Image.Image:
    image = Image.new('1', (64, 64))  # B&W 64x64
    drawing = ImageDraw.Draw(image)
    drawing.rectangle((0, 0, 64, 64), fill='white')
    drawing.pieslice(((0, 0), (63, 63)),
                     -start_angle,
                     -start_angle+180,
                     fill='black')
    return image


def read_input_data(num_images: int, image_folder: Path) -> typing.Tuple[
        np.ndarray,
        np.ndarray]:
    """ Read input data from the image folder.

    :returns: (images, labels)
    """
    labels = []
    if image_folder.exists():
        with (image_folder / 'labels.csv').open() as f:
            for line in f:
                labels.append(float(line))
    image_count = len(labels)
    if image_count != num_images:
        # Size has changed, so recreate the input data.
        shutil.rmtree(image_folder, ignore_errors=True)
        create_images(num_images, image_folder)
        return read_input_data(num_images, image_folder)
    label_data = np.array(labels)
    images = np.zeros((image_count, 64, 64))
    for i, image_path in enumerate(sorted(image_folder.glob('*.png'))):
        image = Image.open(image_path)
        bits = np.array(image)
        images[i, :, :] = bits
    return images, label_data


def plot_loss(history):
    plt.plot(history.history['loss'], label='loss')
    plt.plot(history.history['val_loss'], label='val_loss')
    plt.ylim(bottom=0)
    plt.xlabel('Epoch')
    plt.ylabel('Error [angle]')
    plt.legend()
    plt.grid(True)
    plt.show()


def demo():
    image = create_image(226.634)
    LivePillowImage(image).display()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
elif __name__ == '__live_coding__':
    demo()
```

At the end, I see this output:

```
Trained for 0:00:09.155005
           Mean absolute error [game value]
dnn_model                         92.051697
7/7 [==============================] - 0s 4ms/step
[210.474 147.593 327.796 120.112 163.402 178.04  333.604 342.488 119.694
 240.8  ]
[177.15  181.242 181.242 181.242 181.242 181.242 181.242 181.242 181.242
 181.242]
```

You can see that all the predictions are close to 180°.

Comment: a single convolution and no pooling at all is not gonna do much. I mean, it could, if the convolution learns to build a bank of edge filters and the dense layer learns to look at results in the picture's center. if this trains badly, maybe the training data is insufficient or the labeling is, or the encoding you chose for the angle. remember, it's a neural network. its concept of numbers is analog and somewhat logarithmic. you really shouldn't encode these numbers as degrees. you might want to request the network to regress the `sin` and `cos` of the angle?

Comment: oh and 200 channels on the convolution is excessive. to get an idea of the gradient, _just two_ kernels are the mathematical minimum required. four perhaps, if you keep using any activation function on that layer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem lies in the way you process your data. In general it is a very unsafe idea to rely on some files ordering for your ML model. Instead store inputs and corresponding labels in one spot, in a database of some sort.

```
 for i, image_path in enumerate(sorted(image_folder.glob('*.png'))):
        image = Image.open(image_path)
        bits = np.array(image)
        images[i, :, :] = bits
```

This specific loop is wrong, because **string ordering** is not the same as **number ordering**. So if you sort file names you will get for example

image234.png < image3.png

as this is **lexicographic** sorting.

Consequently your entire data has completely shuffled labels, and thus your model can't learn anything but to predict a mean (which you see now). If you were to generate just 12 images, you would end up with something like:

```
  Image1  -> Label1
  Image10 -> Label2
  Image11 -> Label3
  Image12 -> Label4
  Image2  -> Label5
  Image3  -> Label6
  Image4  -> Labe7
  Image5  -> Label8
  Image6  -> Label9
  Image7  -> Label10
  Image8  -> Label11
  Image9  -> Label12
```

One fix could be to change the loop above to

```
 for i in range(len(label_data)):
        image_path = image_folder / f"image{i}.png" # some logic here to point into the correct file using i
        image = Image.open(image_path)
        bits = np.array(image)
        images[i, :, :] = bits
```

After fixing it, you should be able to learn your mapping even with a tiny MLP, you don't even need a convolution for that.

```
    model = keras.Sequential(
        [
            layers.Flatten(),
            layers.Dense(32),
            layers.Dense(1)])
```

and training for 300 epochs gives

[image]

Comment: I feel like such a newb making a mistake like that! Now that I have the data clean, I can experiment with the model, which was the point of the exercise.

Comment: Don't worry, most of the errors in ML in retrospect look like this. It is  just an interesting property of this field, that various simple (in retrospect) issues still make your code run, and produce results that can be interpreted in many ways.

Comment: BTW, I love your [gamevoycolor.com](https://gamevoycolor.com/) dating game. Good luck with it!

Answer (score 2):

Thanks to [lejlot's patient answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77163422/4794), I found my silly sorting bug. However, my model still didn't work.

```
model = keras.Sequential(
    [layers.Conv2D(num_channels,
                   kernel_size,
                   padding='same',
                   activation='relu',
                   input_shape=(image_height, image_width, 1),
                   activity_regularizer=regularizer),
     layers.Dense(64, activation='relu'),
     layers.Dense(64, activation='relu'),
     layers.Dense(1)])
```

His model was much simpler, but I wanted to learn how to use `Conv2D` layers for more complex problems. After reading [another tutorial](https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/images/cnn) on using them for classification, I tried adding a `Flatten` layer before the `Dense` layers.

```
model = keras.Sequential(
    [layers.Conv2D(num_channels,
                   kernel_size,
                   padding='same',
                   activation='relu',
                   input_shape=(image_height, image_width, 1),
                   activity_regularizer=regularizer),
     layers.Flatten(),
     layers.Dense(64, activation='relu'),
     layers.Dense(64, activation='relu'),
     layers.Dense(1)])
```

That works really well, and can fit the data in 25 epochs.

```
Trained for 0:00:09.873203
           Mean absolute error [angle]
dnn_model                     4.833055
7/7 [==============================] - 0s 3ms/step
[210.474 147.593 327.796 120.112 163.402 178.04  333.604 342.488 119.694
 240.8  ]
[206.194 147.967 317.917 120.808 161.737 177.634 327.112 342.938 120.33
 231.055]
```

lejlot's recommended model is much simpler:

```
model = keras.Sequential(
    [
        layers.Flatten(),
        layers.Dense(32),
        layers.Dense(1)])
```

But it doesn't perform as well, even after 300 epochs.

```
Trained for 0:00:10.439293
           Mean absolute error [angle]
dnn_model                     21.22843
7/7 [==============================] - 0s 833us/step
[210.474 147.593 327.796 120.112 163.402 178.04  333.604 342.488 119.694
 240.8  ]
[225.25  156.989 325.547 123.832 111.674  89.614 308.756 331.706 122.509
 237.6  ]
```

Answer (score -2):

make a deeper model

```
model = keras.Sequential(
    [layers.Conv2D(32,
                   3,
                   padding='same',
                   activation='relu',
                   input_shape=(image_height, image_width, 1),
                   activity_regularizer=regularizer),
     layers.Conv2D(64,
                   3,
                   padding='same',
                   activation='relu',
                   input_shape=(image_height, image_width, 1),
                   activity_regularizer=regularizer),
     layers.Dense(128, activation='relu'),
     layers.Dense(64, activation='relu'),
     layers.Dense(1)])
```

Comment: OPs problems have nothing to do with the  archtecture. This problem could be solved even by a tiny MLP. "Just make the model deeper/bigger" is a very bad prior to have to learn/understand ML